# how would i add an icon to my save file?

Tags: java, icons, save

right now, i can save a file using JFileChooser, but how would i added an icon to the file that i saved?

```
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new CLVFilter()); 
 int returnValue = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(frame); 

 if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){ 
    try{ 
         //filename consists of path 
         String filename = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString(); 
         FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filename); 
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 

         out.write(SingleIntersection.this.getContentsOfObject()); 
         out.close(); 

      }catch (Exception excep){//Catch exception if any 
          System.err.println("Error: " + excep.getMessage()); 
      } 
  }
```

Comment: @Slaks, he's probably referring to the presentation of the file in the operating system.

Comment: so i guess i cant use java to add icon to the file i saved, well, thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 2):

An icon is something your operating system displays (as mentioned by Andy Thomas-Cramer). All you need to specify is the file extension while creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

The file icon is dependent on the file type. This association (type-icon) is done by the operating system (in windows it depends on the file name extension). [You may change the association with java code](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/), but not the icon of a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on OSX, you should also look at the Apple Java Extensions, specifically [FileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eio/FileManager.html). Calling `setFileType(int)` may get you the desired results.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any non-JNI way to *write* to the [Resource Fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork).

Answer (score 0):

We have to set a icon file using windows registry.

eg : your extension .expr

then create icon file for this using registry.